# How to get client area size of window in SDL2

Tags: c++, window, sdl-2

How can I get the resolution of window without taking border into account in SDL2? I need the function just like `GetClientRect` in WinAPI, but it seems like there is no equal function in SDL2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [SDL_GetWindowSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSize), you can grab the width and height of the client window.

```
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", 0, 0, 800, 600, 0);
int width;
int height;
SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
```

> width = 800, height = 600

Comment: Do you know what function `GetClientRect` does? You answer is not correct. I don't need the whole window parameters.

Comment: You only need to use [SDL_GetWindowSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSize) then.

Comment: The function I mentioned uses only the drawable area and not the borders. I tested both with and without the SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS flag in SDL_CreateWindow.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It was just the SDL creates window not taking the borders into account, unlike WinAPI. Weird, isn't it? Accepted your answer.